# How do I use the branch statement in ARM if there are multiple conditions in the if statement?

Tags: arm

How do I use the branch statement **in ARM** if there are multiple conditions in the if statement? For example, if (r6 == last_index && difference == 2) I want to change these statements using the branch statement.

Comment: `cmp rw, rx; cmpeq ry, rz; beq label`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, if rw and rx are the same, and ry and rz are different, the zero flag of cpsr is 1, and the branch statement is executed.

Comment: If `rw == rx`, the zero flag is set to one by `cmp rw, rx`. Consequently, `cmpeq ry, rz` is executed, because its condition (zero flag set) is met. If `ry != rz`, the zero flag is then cleared. Consequently, the `beq` is not executed, since its condition (zero flag set) is false.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional Execution for "And" in ARM syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823486/conditional-execution-for-and-in-arm-syntax)